# Angular 6 variable undefined when it is defined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a variable in a component with a predefined value `path`.

After upgrading from Angular 6.0 to 6.1.7, it is showing as `undefined`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  path: string = '/';

  constructor(public route: Router) {
    console.log(this.path)
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.route.events.subscribe((route)=>{
      this.path = (route as any).url;
    })
    this.getFeatured();
  }
}
```

Statement causing error in template:

```
*ngIf="!path.includes('/reports') && !path.includes('/reviews') && !path.includes('/users')"
```

I do not think its an async issue since it logs it into the console:

[image]

Comment: Is that the template of the `AppComponent` component or is it the template of a different one?

Comment: @Danziger Yep, when I commented out that piece of code and everything start to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after I traced your code, this happens because simply the subscription is for an `event` rather than a `route` (Of course the naming wouldn't matter, just the semantics).

So the last event that fires in the cycle of navigation, is a `scrollEvent`, which doesn't contain a key `url`, thus resulting in undefined.

I think you will need to check the type of the event fired to be of type `NavigationEnd` by doing something like that :

```
this.route.events.subscribe((event)=>{
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
      this.path = (event as any).url;
    }
})
```

**Edit**:

Here is the log to understand what I meant exactly, the latest event (or for fact might be any event in a bigger application), might not contain the `url` property :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.. But it still doesn't seem to work. I removed the `route.events.subscribe()` code block entirely and seem to still face this issue. Now all I have is a defined string

Comment: Oh man, I'm not sure then. Does it work fine but just throwing a console error ? if yes you can use `path?.includes()` ? If you can share more code maybe there's something missing

Comment: Oh it seems to be working. But now I get `Cannot find name 'NavigationEnd'.`

Comment: That's just typescript missing the import, add `import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'`